# Force ending a route in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my nodejs app I use some sub functions in the route /restapi.

One of this sub functions is looking like:

```
    console.log("Before Oauth");
    await checkTheUser(clipApiID + ':' + clipApiSecret).then(res2 => {
        console.log( "Success: " + res2 );
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Oauth Fehler');
        //stop the route
           res.statusCode = 409; //Wrong validation
           res.json({
               success: 'Wrong validation',
               fails: 0
           });
        //End stop the route
    });
    console.log("After Oauth");
```

I expected that the route will end after the error occurred and the res is send.
But finally the route runs further until end.

I also tried with `"return false"` after res send but also the route runs further.

```
        //stop the route
           res.statusCode = 409; //Wrong validation
           res.json({
               success: 'Wrong validation',
               fails: 0
           });
           return false;
        //End stop the route
```

I added the "Before OAuth" and "After OAuth" message to check if there is a asynchronous issue. But the log shows:

- Before OAuth
- OAuth Fehler
- After OAuth

Finally I tried with next and added

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.message); // Log error message in our server's console
    if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500; 
    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        success: err.message,
        fails: 0
    }); 
});
```

and use

```
   //stop the route
   let err = new Error(`Oauth Error`); /
   err.statusCode = 401;
   return next(err);
   //End stop the route
```

Iam confused that no one of this solution will stop the route for further execution. Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `res.end()`?

Comment: You're saying that it goes to the next middleware/controller/whatever after you call `res.status(...).json(...)`? I am assuming you're using a middleware function to check if user is authorized to make the request - show the full middleware and how you're using it in `express`.

Answer (score 0):

Why the await and after that you write .then and .catch ? 
And what do you mean by

> I expected that the route will end after the error occurred and the
>   res is send. But finally the route runs further until end.

I think you misunderstood the await.
you can either write

```
checkTheUser(clipApiID + ':' + clipApiSecret).then(dataInvokedInPromiseResolve=> {
        console.log( "Success: " + dataInvokedInPromiseResolve);
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)}
```

or with the function declared async

```
try {
dataInvokedInPromiseResolve = await checkTheUser(clipApiID + ':' + clipApiSecret);
console.log( "Success: " + dataInvokedInPromiseResolve);
}catch (err) {console.log(err)}//don't forget to catch
```

Ow and to stop the route

```
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Oauth Fehler');
    //stop the route
       res.statusCode = 409; //Wrong validation
       res.json({
           success: 'Wrong validation',
           fails: 0
       });
return //add your return
}
```

Comment: The await is to make sure that the route waits until the sub function is executes. The route contain many sub functions. Each will wait until other is ready. If an error occur I have to stop the route and return an error status and I have to avoid further execution. Common a "return" will cancel execution of a function. But the route, that is a function will not stop. It will call every sub function until end of the route. But this will cause many errors, a chain effect.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing `await someAsyncCall.then(...).catch(...)` - this is fine if you that's what you need, especially for caching `errors` so you don't have to rely just on the `try/catch`.... @ingo you're missing things from your code sample that affect this route handler so it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing the rest, or at least the relevant call.

Comment: @goto1 You're right, it's not wrong but in my opinion, you should use one way or the other, to have consistency in the code, and (not 100%sure ) you can try/catch inside of try/catch

Comment: @RenaudReguieg in my opinion doing `await asyncCall().catch(err => err)` to see if it returned an error for just that one specific call is **a lot better** than using `try/catch` inside of a `try/catch` - this just doesn't feel right. This talk is pretty good that talks about using this type of approach - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YkUCxvaLEk.

Comment: @goto1 without even watching the video await asyncCall().catch(err => err)
pleases me a lot. I assume i can write it that way : const result = await asyncCall().catch(err => err) i didn't know that you could do it, thank you for pointing that to me, and you are right an error for a call is better, i'll do it in the future, thank you :)

Comment: @RenaudReguieg yeah no problem! And yes, I find it very handy to check if `result` for some async call resulted in an error before proceeding, so I'd definitely keep this approach in mind when you find yourself in a need of a similar solution.